# Having auth-secret persist on a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: nginx, authentication, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a Kubernetes cluster on Google Cloud that has a couple of environments that we want to secure from the public. I changed the Kubernetes Ingress settings to the following:

```
kind: Ingress

metadata:
  name: web-develop-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 25m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: [secret here]
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: "Please enter the password for dev"
```

This works and prompts me to enter the password for the dev environment, but this does not persist. I can't seem to find settings to make this persist through the entire session, so that we only have to enter the passphrase once rather than every call requiring the team to re-enter the passphrase.

How can I make the session authentication persistent through the entire session on the Kubernetes Nginx Ingress Controller settings?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, we were calling an authentication header that was labeled the same as the auth-header for Nginx Ingress Controller. Changing our header to "X-Authentication" fixed this issue.